# Use OpenGL or Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

There is not much experience with `OpenGL` to create a two-dimensional scene. I decided to work with 3D and got up with this question: how best?

1) Use a normal `OpenGL`?

2) Work with `OpenGL` through Qt?

The main goal - to provide real-world experience working with graphics. And these questions were formed:

1) Which of the options used in real game development (when the company originally wrote the engine)?

2) Which of the options would be more advantageous for an employer? If I have experience with `OpenGL` or `OpenGL ES in Qt`?

P.S.I'm sorry, Not very good at English. I hope for an answer!

Comment: OpenGL and Qt are not exclusive, though. Eat a burger or burger + coke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt is an UI library, it has nothing to do with whether you wanna use OpenGL or not.

> OpenGL and Qt are not exclusive, though. Eat a burger or burger + coke? – [rolevax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3720890/rolevax).

if you want your application have a nice UI when you're not in 3D mode, you need a UI library, for example, game start screens.

Game Engines are developed based on 3D libraries like OpenGL DirectX Metal etc.

none of the options would be more advantageous for an employer. It's just libraries, you can just learn it if you're good at coding.

Answer (score -1):

Qt is a GUI library, not a rendering library. You can create an OpenGL context using the QOpenGL class. Although OpenGL is a 3D API, it's very much possible to render 2D graphics by using an orthagonal projection matrix and not using the Z coordinate.

For 2D graphics, though, I recommend using a library like SDL which is very simple and high-level. There are also a ton of games that use it.